# Which test to use in a matched control study with unequal sample sizes?

Tags: missing-data, biostatistics, paired-data, matching

I am performing a study in which I matched patients with treatment A 1:1 to patients with treatment B. Patients were then contacted for follow-up, since not all patients responded, the sample sizes are not the same size (34 in group A and 36 in group B).

I planned to use paired t-tests, McNemar tests, and Wilcoxon signed rank tests to compare the characteristics and outcomes between the two groups.
However, since the sample sizes are  not equal, I cannot use paired tests.

Which tests should I use? Is it acceptable to use unpaired tests here or is there another solution?